# How to emulate Python's for-else statement in C

Tags: c

Below is a Python prime number program with a default else condition.  I want to reproduce this in C but I haven't made it work the same way as Python:

```
for ix, num_float in enumerate(numbers):
        num = int(num_float)
        result = 0

        if num > 1:
            for i in range(2,num):
                if (num % i) == 0:
                    result = 0
                    out_array.append(result)
                    break
                else:
                    result = num
                    out_array.append(result)
            else:
                result = 0
                out_array.append(result)
```

In Python the default (final) else condition fires if (a) the input number (num) is 2 or less, or (b) it reaches the end of the range of 2,num without finding a prime number, which triggers the break statement.

I reproduced this in C; it compiles and runs, and it matches the expected output closely but it's not the same.  It does not write the default condition.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers_length; i++){

    num = (int64_t)numbers[i];
    int range_ctr;

    if (num > 1){
        for (range_ctr = 2; range_ctr < num; range_ctr++){
            if ((num%range_ctr) == 0){
                result = 0;
                list_of_results[list_of_results_ctr] = result;
                list_of_results_ctr++; 
                break; }
            else if ((num%range_ctr) != 0){
                result = num;
                list_of_results[list_of_results_ctr] = result;
                list_of_results_ctr++; }
        else {
            result = 0;
            list_of_results[list_of_results_ctr] = result;
            list_of_results_ctr++; }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, how can I code the default condition in C the same way as Python, as described above?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference in the output?

Comment: Where it should write a zero as the default condition, it does not write it.

Comment: I never actually heard of `for-else` in C. Not sure if it's a good idea to force that mindset into C code since I'm not sure how other C devs will react to it. -- Granted I'm not answering your question but then again this is just a comment.

Comment: If there is no C-standard way to reproduce this exactly as in Python, I may have to use a different way of picking up the default condition.

Comment: You should probably avoid using loop-else in Python as well. Allegedly, BDFL Guido van Rossum [wishes the feature had not been added](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-October/006157.html).

Comment: Then it sounds like this construct won't work in C and I'll have to write an alternate default condition.

Comment: The typical options for testing "did my loop break early?" after the loop has completed are a) test the loop counter against its max possible value and b) test a flag that was set in the code that broke out of the loop early.

Comment: Your second option -- the flag -- should work here.

Comment: @RTC222 Unlike Python, indentation does not matter in C. The way you formatted the C code is misleading, because the last `else` actually pairs with the `if` / `else if`, not with the `for` loop.

Comment: Are you referring to my question above, or to my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a standard C way to emulate the default "else" condition in Python, here is what works for me in C:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers_length; i++){

    num = (int64_t)numbers[i];
    int found = 0;
    int range_ctr;

    if (num > 1){
        for (range_ctr = 2; range_ctr < num; range_ctr++){
            if ((num%range_ctr) == 0){
                result = 0;
                list_of_results[list_of_results_ctr] = result;
                list_of_results_ctr++; 
                found = 1;
                break; }
            else if ((num%range_ctr) != 0){
                result = num;
                list_of_results[list_of_results_ctr] = result;
                list_of_results_ctr++; }
        }

        if (found == 0){
            result = 0;
            list_of_results[list_of_results_ctr] = result;
            list_of_results_ctr++; }                    
    }
}
```

I added a flag called "found" and moved the default condition outside the for loop.

Thanks to all who answered.